# Tag merge request: [phonegap] and [cordova]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, tag-synonyms

[cordova](/questions/tagged/cordova) is the new name of [phonegap](/questions/tagged/phonegap). I think these two tags should be merged.

Comment: Isn't PhoneGap the new name of Cordova?

Comment: @ThePower: Feel free to edit it to match the fact (I'm not too sure myself, though). I'm more sure about the fact that they are the same, though, at least to user of the library.

Comment: It really [hasn't been renamed](http://phonegap.com/2012/03/19/phonegap-cordova-and-what%E2%80%99s-in-a-name/). "PhoneGap is a distribution of Apache Cordova." Like Chrome is a distribution of Chromium.

Comment: @vcsjones: You are correct. However, I think most of the post are from Phonegap developers (as defined in the article you pointed out), rather than contributors.

Comment: Apache Cordova used to be Nitobi Phonegap. Now it's open source, and Adobe have their own product called Phonegap based on Cordova.

Comment: @WillshawMedia: So would that be a problem to the currently merged status of the 2 tags? (I really don't know so I am asking).

Comment: Yeah I really don't think they should be merged. I don't use Phonegap, I use Cordova.

Comment: @WillshawMedia: You can ask a new question in Meta.SO to request the 2 tags to be split, referring this question. Originally, I accepted the answer (to keep them separated) before the tag merge happened, so I don't know why the 2 tags are merged.

Comment: Please, make them separate tags again, they are not the same and it would be helpful to have separate tags. There are a lot of Phonegap users that don't even know what Cordova is and get confused when they tag is changed. Please, upvote https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337612/remove-phonegap-as-synonym-of-cordova-tag-and-make-it-independent-again

Comment: @jcesar: If you have already made a new question on meta stackoverflow, there is no point in putting comment here, since it's a discussion that is dated nearly 5 years ago.

Comment: @nhahtdh I just wanted some visibility as my proposal had more than 20 upvotes, I created it 5 months ago and nothing was done about it. They have just been splitted, so maybe commenting on old related questions did the trick. But sorry to bother you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm a PhoneGap developer using Build, and disagree with this merge. PhoneGap has split off one part of its product, the engine, and the two will diverge more as time goes on. PhoneGap Build is probably going to dominate [phonegap](/questions/tagged/phonegap) questions in the near future.

As a developer of apps *using* PhoneGap, I think of [phonegap](/questions/tagged/phonegap) first. If I were contributing code to the Cordova project, I'd use [cordova](/questions/tagged/cordova).

Also, it's very likely someone else will come along and use the Cordova engine to do something similar to PhoneGap, and will spin off their own distro. The article a commenter mentioned, [PhoneGap, Cordova, and what’s in a name?](http://phonegap.com/2012/03/19/phonegap-cordova-and-what%E2%80%99s-in-a-name/), mentioned the WebKit analogy and I think that's an appropriate way to look at it. A question might use [chrome](/questions/tagged/chrome), [safari](/questions/tagged/safari), and/or [webkit](/questions/tagged/webkit) (or any combination of the three), but they are still separate tags.

Comment: Moments ago I clicked on the "phonegap" and "cordova" tags, then hit the "learn more" link on each one. The two tag wiki I see are almost word-for-word identical, leaving me to wonder if there is any real difference between them. Would someone who understands the difference between them (i.e., someone who is not me) please edit that tag wiki to give clear advice on: When should I should tag my questions with "phonegap"? When should I should tag my questions with "cordova"?

Comment: @DavidCary if possible I would tag them as both - Cordova is the open source technology that Phonegap is built on. Phonegap 3.5 was released a little while after Cordova 3.5, I guess so Adobe had time to upgrade their Phonegap Build service. I think Phonegap is also integrated into the Brackets code editor, but not Cordova. ThinkingStiff's analogy of Webkit and Chrome/Safari is fantastic - perhaps the Chromium project and Chrome itself is closer though. Sometimes you don't know if the problem is specifically with the core (Webkit/Cordova) or the final product (Chrome/Phonegap).

Comment: please, upvote this proposal to separate the tags https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337612/remove-phonegap-as-synonym-of-cordova-tag-and-make-it-independent-again

Answer (score 1):

They are different things even if developers using PhoneGap may not know where one ends and the other begins. (I know [I often don't](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19459111/436641)!) This is compounded by the fact that lots of code that used to be PhoneGap is now Cordova.

The blurring is not entirely unlike someone not understanding if a problem they are facing is in (e.g.) Safari or in WebKit. (As far as I know, this analogy was first popularized by Brian LeRoux.)

The fact that they are different things may be easier to see by their different code bases:

- Cordova CLI source code: https://github.com/apache/cordova-cli
- PhoneGap CLI source code: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-cli

PhoneGap depends on Cordova but Cordova can be used without PhoneGap. You can see this by looking in the `package.json` file for the respective projects.

In theory, other projects may arise (or perhaps already have--I don't know much about Icenium etc.) that use Cordova as the underlying engine. Therefore, having separate tags is probably useful.