# Why was my tag silently replaced with another one?

Tags: support, tags

I asked a question about "phonegap" and added the [phonegap](/questions/tagged/phonegap) and [sencha](/questions/tagged/sencha) tags.

But when I submitted the question, the actual tags were different: [cordova](/questions/tagged/cordova) appeared instead of [phonegap](/questions/tagged/phonegap). Why did this happen? Did I do something wrong?

Comment: They are synonyms http://stackoverflow.com/tags/cordova/synonyms

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you can see in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cordova/synonyms, they are synonyms:

> The following tags will be remapped to [cordova](/questions/tagged/cordova):
>
> [phonegap](/questions/tagged/phonegap)
>
> [see all tag synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms)

It means exactly what happened to you: any question tagged with one of the synonyms will automatically be remapped to the "master" one.

Comment: So thats it!! Thank you..

Comment: YOu're welcome! Now I see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137732/tag-merge-request-phonegap-and-cordova where the tag merge was requested. (Somebody just updated that question so it appeared in the front page)